# Visibility issues with Pex

Tags: pex

I tried to use generate unit tests for some parts of code in my project. But all I get is the same error everytime, and the messages offered are'nt very helpful to arrive at a solution. Pex says that the code is not visible to it. But if i add the required classes and their dependencies to another solution, it works fine. Has anyone else faced this issue and found an answer?

Comment: maybe show some of the code/methods and the exact exception message and if possible stack-trace?

Comment: Are you facing any error / exceptions? Because for me it is working fine. Env. VS2010 Ultimate, XP SP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue. There was a name mismatch between the name of the project and the name of the assembly. Once I fixed these to be the same name, It was visible by Pex. Sorry for the carelessness.